# what is the equivalent for (?s) y (?m) en powergrep?

Tags: regex, powergrep

When using powergrep, there is an option called: file sectioning and the first 3 options are:

- do not section files.
- line by line
- line by line including line breaks

I am guessing that first option would be similar to Perl's 'm' modifier ("^" matches the start of the string and after each newline; "$" matches before each newline and at the end of the string), and the option *Dot matches new lines*, would be as if Perl's 's' modifier was used ("." matches all characters rather than excluding newlines).

I don't understand the two following options. *Line by line* and still you can turn on the check box dot matches new lines. And *line by line including line breaks* would be (?s) modifier again, so I don't understand those options.

Please can somebody explain those options? and the relation with s and m modifiers.

Comment: How is tag perl relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know powergrep, but it sounds like those they control against what you are matching.

- "Do not section files" matches against the entire file.

  ```
  my $file = do { local $/; <$fh> };
  $file =~ /.../;
  ```
- "Line by line including line breaks" matches against each line.

  ```
  while (my $line = <$fh>) {
     $line =~ /.../;
  }
  ```
- "Line by line" matches against each line, chomped.

  ```
  while (<$fh>) {
     chomp( my $chomped_line = $_ );
     $chomped_line =~ /.../;
  }
  ```

There's no doubt that "Dot matches new lines" is equivalent to the `s` modifier.

Comment: thanks for the corrections and answer. now is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> To turn on dot matches newline for one regex, put (?s) in front of it.
>
> (?n) or -line enables what Tcl calls "newline-sensitive matching". The dot and negated character classes will not match newlines. The caret and dollar will match after and before newlines. Specifying (?n) or -line is the same as specifying (?pw) or -linestop -lineanchor.
>
> (?m) is a historical synonym for (?n).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html